# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number', Angular version update issue

Tags: angular

```
for (const field in this.form.controls) {
      let control : any = form.get(field);// Getting error on this line
      if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid && control.errors) {
        if (control.errors["pattern"]) console.log(field + " cannot contain special characters");
        if (control.errors["required"]) console.log("Please enter " + field);
      }
    }
```

Error :

```
L103:    let control : any = form.get(field);
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
```

I have updated angular version to 16. After that I started getting this type of errors on multiple forms.

Comment: `let control : any = this.form.get(field);`? See the "this", really I don't know if you pass the form to your function or not

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vs code I'll suggest you to restart your vs code.
Sometimes, Intellisense seems to mess up with imports or types.

Comment: Restarted VS code, but still not working.

Comment: Can you provide what you're getting in console.log of 
console.log(this.form.controls)
console.log(field )
console.log(form.get(field))

Comment: try adding debugger when loop start and see the results

Comment: Actually I have updated angular version from 5 to 16. And due to this errors, I am not able to run or debug application.

Comment: Getting this errors at the time of build only

Comment: comment that line and then check the console log